# How can I rotate an extern FlexScan monitor on a Sony VPC-Z13V5E Notebook?

Tags: multiple-monitors, rotate

a coworker tries to rotate an Eizo Flexscan S2243W (widescreen) by 90 degrees on his Sony Vaio VPC-Z13V5E notebook. He runs Windows 7.
I downloaded and (re)installed the graphics drivers from the German Sony site, but still wasn't able to find a rotate function in the graphics settings.

Normally, it is a simple menu point in the graphics settings, right? I can't find it. I guess the problem is the graphics card, but maybe it just doesn't support widescreen rotating? Could that be a problem?

I called the Sony support, and after about 2 weeks of calling back and forth and trying various things, they now recommend reinstalling Windows and trying again. I don't want to do that as the OS is only 3 weeks new (and I spent a good time configuring his PC).

Does anyone have any idea on what could cause this? Is this maybe normal with some widescreen monitors, or should the graphics card normally be able to do this?

Thanks in advance,
 Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying in the graphics-vendor-specific configuration, or just in the Windows display properties?  Right-click desktop, Screen Resolution...then select the display and change the Orientation option.

I've yet to see a functioning Windows 7 graphics driver that disabled this functionality...but I guess it's not impossible.  How is the monitor cabled?

Comment: I have tried both the Nvidia menu and the Windows menu - both did not have an orientation option. (I have seen them on other Nvidia menus and on other Windows machines; they just weren't there on this one). The monitor is cabled via VGA - the notebook doesn't have a DVI port.

Comment: @Alexx - This might be a consequence of the connection being analog as well, then.  Unfortunately I haven't run into this and don't have anything comparable to test with so I doubt I'll be much more help here - sorry!

Comment: Well, thank you anyway. Do you know if there is a way to get a digital signal out of the Notebook? A VGI->DVA adapter won't help, I guess. I don't remember if his computer had a HDMI port, but if it has one, would it make sense to try that?

Comment: An HDMI or DisplayPort port would be worth a try.  I would be interested to see if you could rotate it using a USB to DVI adapter, for that matter...

Comment: I can try to convince my boss to buy one. You do mean those extern graphic cards, right? It's not just a cable with an USB port on one side and a DVI one on the other?

Comment: Right, I mean something like http://sewelldirect.com/Sewell-Minideck-USB-to-DVI-Display-Adapter.asp

Answer (score 1):

THe answer to this is unfortunately simple -- Sony is selling a top of the line ie hugely expensive computer that DOES NOT HAVE THE BASIC ABILITY to rotate an attached monitor. 
The Z-series simply CANNOT DO THIS.  You have to return the computer to Sony and ask them to install a compatible graphics card which is an upgraded Nvidia.  At the hotline, no one knows this, you will have to tell them.  The graphics card installed on the Sony Z series is not compatible with the system,  they have made a big mistake. 
They ought to be selling them with the notice that this computer cannot be used with an attached monitor in portrait mode.